# Deserialize nested json string leads to a null value

Tags: c#, json

I have a json string which I want to deserialize to access specific members.

```
string sResponse = "{\"BALANCERESPONSE\":{\"@xmlns\":\"\",\"RESPONSECODE\":\"0\",\"RESPONSEMESSAGE\":\"Success\"}}";
Response conObj = new Response();
conObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(sResponse);

public class BALANCERESPONSE
{
    public string RESPONSECODE { get; set; }
    public string RESPONSEMESSAGE { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public BALANCERESPONSE resp_onse { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting a `null` value in the `resp_onse` property. What I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input string doesn't mention the name but the type. Hence, the property is not recognized and will remain `null`.

New:

```
string sResponse = "{\"resp_onse\":{\"@xmlns\":\"\",\"RESPONSECODE\":\"0\",\"RESPONSEMESSAGE\":\"Success\"}}";
                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Old:

```
string sResponse = "{\"BALANCERESPONSE\":{\"@xmlns\":\"\",\"RESPONSECODE\":\"0\",\"RESPONSEMESSAGE\":\"Success\"}}";
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```